# WCF fails, when my tablet isn't in charger

Tags: wcf, windows-phone

I have very interesting problem and I dont have idea, how to solved it. I have WCF application - WCF client is my Windows Phone 8 and WCF host is my tablet with Windows 8. When tablet is in charger, everything works right, but when I disconnect charger, WCF starts be slower and fails. I tried to run this WCF host on different devices and it worked alright, but i need to run the WCF host on this tablet without charger. How to do it?

Comment: I would hope there is a setting somewhere in the tablet to modify the connectivity behavior when the tablet is on/off-charge. It is very common for battery management to change the connectivity profile depending on this. However, as I'm not a windows mobile user I can't help you specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Problem was that the wifi hotspot was created from my laptop and for some reason the tablet didnt like it.... When I created wifi from router, it worked fine.